# Multivariable Calculus with Tensors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, tensors, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book at the undergraduate level on multivariable calculus (for a 2nd course of multivariable calculus) that introduces and makes use of tensors to describe higher order derivatives -- and maybe differential forms for integration.  Does anyone know of a multivariable book that takes this tact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculus on Manifolds - Spivak - A beautiful short little book.  It carries you all the way to proving Stokes theorem.

Comment: I looked at that book earlier and I can't remember anything on tensors or even higher order derivatives except partial derivatives.  I believe it does go over differential forms, but I'd really like a textbook that goes into tensor theory.  Does this book go into that topic very far?

Comment: Must have been a different one of his books then.  Take a look at: http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-On-Manifolds-Approach-Classical/dp/0805390219 and click the look inside option.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it a textbook, it's very trimmed down.  If you wanted to teach with it, I think you would need to augment with other notes  / problems.

Comment: @user244322 It's in Chapter 4 - I couldn't recall either, and had to dig out my copy.